# How to gain additional points on the CoS (Tier 2 UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, australian-citizens

I am an Australian speech pathologist who has been offered a permanent full time position with the NHS. I am currently sitting on 40 points for my application for CoS although have been rejected several times due to the visa allocation requiring >46 points. Does anyone have any ideas of how to obtain additional points? Unfortunately my role was previously on the job shortage list although this is not the case at present.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the only thing that affects a CoS application is the labor market tests and the salary (e.g., https://www.admin.ox.ac.uk/personnel/permits/tier2/overseas/formalcosrequests/), but I cannot find the official website. You are presumably getting 20 points for the passing the resident labor market test and another 20 points for a salary between £40,000 - £40,999.99. to get to over 46 points you would need the salary to be £50,000 - £54,999.99 to get 30 points.